# Get [operator name] from [phone number] range

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring, procedure

**Table**: 
[image: Table image]

There's a phone number (+74859298085 for example). Can I get the operator name (part1+part2) from table above. Where to start?

Comment: You will have to split that phone number into a "code" and "value". Then search in that table for the row where the "code" is equal and the "value" is between "begin" and "end". The problem part is how to split that phone number.

Comment: i am not seeing any phone +74859298085 in the image.
select replace('operator_name_',operator_name1,'')+replace('operator_name_',operator_name2,'') from table1

Comment: +74859298085 placed in other table.

Comment: Its ambiguous what you want. Bcoz what number you shown does not resembles with the table you have provided. Please provide all the sample data & desired output.

Comment: +74859298085 is sample phone.
+74501925555 let it be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT O.OPERATOR_NAME1, O.OPERATOR_NAME2 
FROM OPERATOR O 
WHERE CONVERT(INT, RIGHT('+74501925555', 7)) BETWEEN O.BEGIN AND O.END;
```

Comment: Do you think the number is in Varchar format. What if the number is in numeric ?

Comment: @Aditya It will work also whether the number is numeric or string